# Duplicate class androidx.navigation.ui. after installing Android Studio on a new device

Tags: java, android, android-studio, build.gradle

I have an Android App as an Android Studio project and I just installed Android Studio on a new device and tried to run the app in an Android Studio Emulator which was not a problem using the old device. However, in the new device I get the errors:

```
 Duplicate class androidx.navigation.ActivityKt found in modules navigation-runtime-2.4.1-runtime (androidx.navigation:navigation-runtime:2.4.1) and navigation-runtime-ktx-2.3.5-runtime (androidx.navigation:navigation-runtime-ktx:2.3.5)
Duplicate class androidx.navigation.ActivityNavArgsLazyKt found in modules navigation-runtime-2.4.1-runtime (androidx.navigation:navigation-runtime:2.4.1) and navigation-runtime-ktx-2.3.5-runtime (androidx.navigation:navigation-runtime-ktx:2.3.5)
Duplicate class androidx.navigation.ActivityNavArgsLazyKt$navArgs$1 found in modules navigation-runtime-2.4.1-runtime (androidx.navigation:navigation-runtime:2.4.1) and navigation-runtime-ktx-2.3.5-runtime (androidx.navigation:navigation-runtime-ktx:2.3.5)
Duplicate class androidx.navigation.ActivityNavigatorDestinationBuilder found in modules navigation-runtime-2.4.1-runtime (androidx.navigation:navigation-runtime:2.4.1) and navigation-runtime-ktx-2.3.5-runtime (androidx.navigation:navigation-runtime-ktx:2.3.5)
Duplicate class androidx.navigation.ActivityNavigatorDestinationBuilderKt found in modules navigation-runtime-2.4.1-runtime (androidx.navigation:navigation-runtime:2.4.1) and navigation-runtime-ktx-2.3.5-runtime (androidx.navigation:navigation-runtime-ktx:2.3.5)
Duplicate class androidx.navigation.ActivityNavigatorExtrasKt found in modules navigation-runtime-2.4.1-runtime (androidx.navigation:navigation-runtime:2.4.1) and navigation-runtime-ktx-2.3.5-runtime (androidx.navigation:navigation-runtime-ktx:2.3.5)
Duplicate class androidx.navigation.AnimBuilder found in modules navigation-common-2.4.1-runtime (androidx.navigation:navigation-common:2.4.1) and navigation-common-ktx-2.3.5-runtime (androidx.navigation:navigation-common-ktx:2.3.5)
Duplicate class androidx.navigation.NavActionBuilder found in modules navigation-common-2.4.1-runtime (androidx.navigation:navigation-common:2.4.1) and navigation-common-ktx-2.3.5-runtime (androidx.navigation:navigation-common-ktx:2.3.5)
Duplicate class androidx.navigation.NavArgsLazy found in modules navigation-common-2.4.1-runtime (androidx.navigation:navigation-common:2.4.1) and navigation-common-ktx-2.3.5-runtime (androidx.navigation:navigation-common-ktx:2.3.5)
Duplicate class androidx.navigation.NavArgsLazyKt found in modules navigation-common-2.4.1-runtime (androidx.navigation:navigation-common:2.4.1) and navigation-common-ktx-2.3.5-runtime (androidx.navigation:navigation-common-ktx:2.3.5)
Duplicate class androidx.navigation.NavArgumentBuilder found in modules navigation-common-2.4.1-runtime (androidx.navigation:navigation-common:2.4.1) and navigation-common-ktx-2.3.5-runtime (androidx.navigation:navigation-common-ktx:2.3.5)
Duplicate class androidx.navigation.NavControllerKt found in modules navigation-runtime-2.4.1-runtime (androidx.navigation:navigation-runtime:2.4.1) and navigation-runtime-ktx-2.3.5-runtime (androidx.navigation:navigation-runtime-ktx:2.3.5)
Duplicate class androidx.navigation.NavDeepLinkDsl found in modules navigation-common-2.4.1-runtime (androidx.navigation:navigation-common:2.4.1) and navigation-common-ktx-2.3.5-runtime (androidx.navigation:navigation-common-ktx:2.3.5)
Duplicate class androidx.navigation.NavDeepLinkDslBuilder found in modules navigation-common-2.4.1-runtime (androidx.navigation:navigation-common:2.4.1) and navigation-common-ktx-2.3.5-runtime (androidx.navigation:navigation-common-ktx:2.3.5)
Duplicate class androidx.navigation.NavDeepLinkDslBuilderKt found in modules navigation-common-2.4.1-runtime (androidx.navigation:navigation-common:2.4.1) and navigation-common-ktx-2.3.5-runtime (androidx.navigation:navigation-common-ktx:2.3.5)
Duplicate class androidx.navigation.NavDestinationBuilder found in modules navigation-common-2.4.1-runtime (androidx.navigation:navigation-common:2.4.1) and navigation-common-ktx-2.3.5-runtime (androidx.navigation:navigation-common-ktx:2.3.5)
Duplicate class androidx.navigation.NavDestinationDsl found in modules navigation-common-2.4.1-runtime (androidx.navigation:navigation-common:2.4.1) and navigation-common-ktx-2.3.5-runtime (androidx.navigation:navigation-common-ktx:2.3.5)
Duplicate class androidx.navigation.NavGraphBuilder found in modules navigation-common-2.4.1-runtime (androidx.navigation:navigation-common:2.4.1) and navigation-common-ktx-2.3.5-runtime (androidx.navigation:navigation-common-ktx:2.3.5)
Duplicate class androidx.navigation.NavGraphBuilderKt found in modules navigation-common-2.4.1-runtime (androidx.navigation:navigation-common:2.4.1) and navigation-common-ktx-2.3.5-runtime (androidx.navigation:navigation-common-ktx:2.3.5)
Duplicate class androidx.navigation.NavGraphKt found in modules navigation-common-2.4.1-runtime (androidx.navigation:navigation-common:2.4.1) and navigation-common-ktx-2.3.5-runtime (androidx.navigation:navigation-common-ktx:2.3.5)
Duplicate class androidx.navigation.NavGraphViewModelLazyKt found in modules navigation-fragment-2.4.1-runtime (androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.4.1) and navigation-fragment-ktx-2.3.5-runtime (androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.3.5)
Duplicate class androidx.navigation.NavGraphViewModelLazyKt$navGraphViewModels$1 found in modules navigation-fragment-2.4.1-runtime (androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.4.1) and navigation-fragment-ktx-2.3.5-runtime (androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.3.5)
Duplicate class androidx.navigation.NavGraphViewModelLazyKt$navGraphViewModels$backStackEntry$2 found in modules navigation-fragment-2.4.1-runtime (androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.4.1) and navigation-fragment-ktx-2.3.5-runtime (androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.3.5)
Duplicate class androidx.navigation.NavGraphViewModelLazyKt$navGraphViewModels$storeProducer$1 found in modules navigation-fragment-2.4.1-runtime (androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.4.1) and navigation-fragment-ktx-2.3.5-runtime (androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.3.5)
Duplicate class androidx.navigation.NavHostKt found in modules navigation-runtime-2.4.1-runtime (androidx.navigation:navigation-runtime:2.4.1) and navigation-runtime-ktx-2.3.5-runtime (androidx.navigation:navigation-runtime-ktx:2.3.5)
Duplicate class androidx.navigation.NavOptionsBuilder found in modules navigation-common-2.4.1-runtime (androidx.navigation:navigation-common:2.4.1) and navigation-common-ktx-2.3.5-runtime (androidx.navigation:navigation-common-ktx:2.3.5)
Duplicate class androidx.navigation.NavOptionsBuilderKt found in modules navigation-common-2.4.1-runtime (androidx.navigation:navigation-common:2.4.1) and navigation-common-ktx-2.3.5-runtime (androidx.navigation:navigation-common-ktx:2.3.5)
Duplicate class androidx.navigation.NavOptionsDsl found in modules navigation-common-2.4.1-runtime (androidx.navigation:navigation-common:2.4.1) and navigation-common-ktx-2.3.5-runtime (androidx.navigation:navigation-common-ktx:2.3.5)
Duplicate class androidx.navigation.NavigatorProviderKt found in modules navigation-common-2.4.1-runtime (androidx.navigation:navigation-common:2.4.1) and navigation-common-ktx-2.3.5-runtime (androidx.navigation:navigation-common-ktx:2.3.5)
Duplicate class androidx.navigation.PopUpToBuilder found in modules navigation-common-2.4.1-runtime (androidx.navigation:navigation-common:2.4.1) and navigation-common-ktx-2.3.5-runtime (androidx.navigation:navigation-common-ktx:2.3.5)
Duplicate class androidx.navigation.ViewKt found in modules navigation-runtime-2.4.1-runtime (androidx.navigation:navigation-runtime:2.4.1) and navigation-runtime-ktx-2.3.5-runtime (androidx.navigation:navigation-runtime-ktx:2.3.5)
Duplicate class androidx.navigation.fragment.DialogFragmentNavigatorDestinationBuilder found in modules navigation-fragment-2.4.1-runtime (androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.4.1) and navigation-fragment-ktx-2.3.5-runtime (androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.3.5)
Duplicate class androidx.navigation.fragment.DialogFragmentNavigatorDestinationBuilderKt found in modules navigation-fragment-2.4.1-runtime (androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.4.1) and navigation-fragment-ktx-2.3.5-runtime (androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.3.5)
Duplicate class androidx.navigation.fragment.FragmentKt found in modules navigation-fragment-2.4.1-runtime (androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.4.1) and navigation-fragment-ktx-2.3.5-runtime (androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.3.5)
Duplicate class androidx.navigation.fragment.FragmentNavArgsLazyKt found in modules navigation-fragment-2.4.1-runtime (androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.4.1) and navigation-fragment-ktx-2.3.5-runtime (androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.3.5)
Duplicate class androidx.navigation.fragment.FragmentNavArgsLazyKt$navArgs$1 found in modules navigation-fragment-2.4.1-runtime (androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.4.1) and navigation-fragment-ktx-2.3.5-runtime (androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.3.5)
Duplicate class androidx.navigation.fragment.FragmentNavigatorDestinationBuilder found in modules navigation-fragment-2.4.1-runtime (androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.4.1) and navigation-fragment-ktx-2.3.5-runtime (androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.3.5)
Duplicate class androidx.navigation.fragment.FragmentNavigatorDestinationBuilderKt found in modules navigation-fragment-2.4.1-runtime (androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.4.1) and navigation-fragment-ktx-2.3.5-runtime (androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.3.5)
Duplicate class androidx.navigation.fragment.FragmentNavigatorExtrasKt found in modules navigation-fragment-2.4.1-runtime (androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.4.1) and navigation-fragment-ktx-2.3.5-runtime (androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.3.5)
Duplicate class androidx.navigation.ui.ActivityKt found in modules navigation-ui-2.4.1-runtime (androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.4.1) and navigation-ui-ktx-2.3.5-runtime (androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.3.5)
Duplicate class androidx.navigation.ui.AppBarConfigurationKt found in modules navigation-ui-2.4.1-runtime (androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.4.1) and navigation-ui-ktx-2.3.5-runtime (androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.3.5)
Duplicate class androidx.navigation.ui.AppBarConfigurationKt$AppBarConfiguration$1 found in modules navigation-ui-2.4.1-runtime (androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.4.1) and navigation-ui-ktx-2.3.5-runtime (androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.3.5)
Duplicate class androidx.navigation.ui.AppBarConfigurationKt$AppBarConfiguration$2 found in modules navigation-ui-2.4.1-runtime (androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.4.1) and navigation-ui-ktx-2.3.5-runtime (androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.3.5)
Duplicate class androidx.navigation.ui.AppBarConfigurationKt$AppBarConfiguration$3 found in modules navigation-ui-2.4.1-runtime (androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.4.1) and navigation-ui-ktx-2.3.5-runtime (androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.3.5)
Duplicate class androidx.navigation.ui.AppBarConfigurationKt$sam$i$androidx_navigation_ui_AppBarConfiguration_OnNavigateUpListener$0 found in modules navigation-ui-2.4.1-runtime (androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.4.1) and navigation-ui-ktx-2.3.5-runtime (androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.3.5)
Duplicate class androidx.navigation.ui.BottomNavigationViewKt found in modules navigation-ui-2.4.1-runtime (androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.4.1) and navigation-ui-ktx-2.3.5-runtime (androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.3.5)
Duplicate class androidx.navigation.ui.CollapsingToolbarLayoutKt found in modules navigation-ui-2.4.1-runtime (androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.4.1) and navigation-ui-ktx-2.3.5-runtime (androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.3.5)
Duplicate class androidx.navigation.ui.MenuItemKt found in modules navigation-ui-2.4.1-runtime (androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.4.1) and navigation-ui-ktx-2.3.5-runtime (androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.3.5)
Duplicate class androidx.navigation.ui.NavControllerKt found in modules navigation-ui-2.4.1-runtime (androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.4.1) and navigation-ui-ktx-2.3.5-runtime (androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.3.5)
Duplicate class androidx.navigation.ui.NavigationViewKt found in modules navigation-ui-2.4.1-runtime (androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.4.1) and navigation-ui-ktx-2.3.5-runtime (androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.3.5)
Duplicate class androidx.navigation.ui.ToolbarKt found in modules navigation-ui-2.4.1-runtime (androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.4.1) and navigation-ui-ktx-2.3.5-runtime (androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.3.5)
```

Here is my build.grandle file:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
}

apply plugin: "androidx.navigation.safeargs"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 31
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.game"
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 31
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        viewBinding {
            enabled = true
        }

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.2'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
    implementation "androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.3"

    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.3.5'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.3.5'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:$nav_version"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:$nav_version"
}
```

Do you know what I can do in order to fix this issue and can you tell me why at the new device it is a problem why at the older device it has not been a problem for years?

Comment: What is `$nav_version`? Why aren't you using that same variable when declaring your other Navigation dependencies (which right now used a fixed value of `2.3.5`?

Comment: @ianhanniballake thanks for your comment. "why aren't you using that same variable when declaring your other Navigation dependencies (which right now used a fixed value of 2.3.5". what do you mean by that

Comment: You seem to be mixing and matching different versions of Navigation dependencies. Why?

Comment: Which ones are you referring to? I always inserted the dependencies that I was told were necessary for certain functionality

Comment: You do see that you have 4 dependencies on the Navigation library right? Two using `$nav_version` and two using `2.3.5`?

Comment: Yes I see that. WHich one is the correct one? I always added the dependencies because I was told by anone (most probably here in Stackoverflow) that I should add it for some specific functionality

Comment: I asked "why are they using different versions", including all four is fine, using different versions for each is not.

Comment: @ianhanniballake: Thanks for your comment. Which one shall I use `$nav_version` or `2.3.5`?

Comment: What is `$nav_version`?

Comment: @ianhanniballake I don't know what `$nav_version` is. I guess it is a library for Android Jetpack navigation or for AndroidX, but I am not sure. What else shall I use instead of it?

Comment: `$nav_version` is a variable you've declared in one of your `build.gradle` files. Find where that variable is declared.

Comment: @ianhanniballake: I have the following command `buildscript {
    ext.nav_version = '2.4.1'` Is that the specificaiton of `$nav_version`? And what exactly would you advice me to do

Comment: @ianhanniballake: Any comments to my last comment? I'll highly appreciate every further comment from you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have four dependencies on Navigation:

```
implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.3.5'
implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.3.5'

implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:$nav_version"
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:$nav_version"
```

As you've stated, you have declared your `$nav_version` as `ext.nav_version = '2.4.1'`.

You can't mix and match versions of Navigation - they all need to match exactly. Since you already have a variable, your `$nav_version`, just use that for all four dependencies. That way, they will always match exactly:

```
// These lines were changed to use $nav_version
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:$nav_version"
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:$nav_version"

// These lines stayed the same
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:$nav_version"
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:$nav_version"
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer and effort Ian. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the last 2 dependencies if you are using kotlin. If you are using java, then remove 5th and 6th dependencies. Sync project, and it should resolve the error.

Comment: thanks moon for your answer. i usw java. why shall i remove the 4th depedency about constraint layout

Comment: Sorry for the wrong number I mentioned before. You should remove 5th and 6th dependency ending with ktx because at run time, compiler get confused between kotlin and java classes and throws this error.